# Ошибка SQL запроса

Tags: sql-server

```sql
select *
from stack.[Список объектов]so
join stack.[Показания счетчиков]po
  on stack.[Лицевые счета].ROW_ID = so.[Объекты-Счет]
and so.[ДатНач] <= '01.11.11'
and so.[ДатКнц] > '01.11.11'
and po.[Объект-Показания] = so.row_id
order by so.[Объекты-Счет]
```

выдает ошибку:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The multi-part identifier "stack.Лицевые счета.ROW_ID" could not be bound.

Comment: проблема в том, что он мне не дает использовать запрос к столбцу stack.[Лицевые счета].ROW_ID после использования join, я новичок, поэтому не могу понять как мне исправить эту проблему(((

Comment: да блин он не редактируется! в верхнем окне все хорошо, а в нижнем без перехода строки(((

Comment: просто появляется 'enter code', когда нажимаю((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что у Вас обозначает stack - имя базы данных? (каталога)

1) Если вы задаете имена объектов с указанием имени каталога, то необходимо задавать также и имя схемы. получится что-то вроде

```
select * 
from stack.dbo.[Список объектов] so
```

и т.д.

2) Вы объединяете stack.dbo.[Список объектов] и stack.[Показания счетчиков] а в условии объединения ссылаетесь на  какие то stack.[Лицевые счета], so.[Объекты-Счет] и т.д.
Дайте структуру таблиц, у Вас явно какая то путаница в понятиях

Comment: все я разобрался))
да я действительно обращался к другой таблице при объединении (думал, что так можно, ет потом до меня дошло, что при объединении так нельзя делать) сделал вложенный запрос в From с выборкой именно тех данных, которые мне нужны в таблице и объединял уже с другой таблицей те данные, которые получились при выборке.
Спасибо, за ответ, он меня наставил на путь истинный =)), если б еще имя знать кому спасибо, и было бы круто исправить касяк с отсутствием переносов в ответе.